Non-transfer to my coinbase wallet due to low priority
I'm just beginning my journey into crypto currencies and its ecosystem. Right now, I received the message below from Coinbase (coinbase@wallet-cb.support) informing me of a non-transfer to my coinbase wallet due to low priority. Does this seem normal to you? Thank you for your feedback and your help in resolving the situation.
"The transfer you made to purchase BNB was not received by the system because my transaction is stored in mempool awaiting validation. Right now your transaction has a very low priority, that's why Mempool is asking you to make a transfer of the same value so that the block increase can be done, and your transfer arrives immediately. Otherwise, we don't know how long it will take to complete your process."

Does this answer your question? Is it normal to be asked for an advance fee on a withdrawal? What you describe looks like a clear scam. The email address is obviously not coinbase.
